# How to parse through the structure variable

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix

I am trying to get an IP address from the user and determine whether it is Class A, B, or C. I am unable to split the addr structure variable to check the bits. Could someone suggest? :). Thanks a lot.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    struct in_addr addr;
    uint32_t temp;
    char *IP;
    int ret = 0;    

    if (argc != 2)
        error(1, errno, "Too many or few arguments\n");
    IP = argv[1];
        ret = inet_aton(IP, &addr);
    if (ret == 0)
        error(1, errno, "Invalid IP- address provided\n");
    printf("The address in the structure is network byte order:(Big- Endian) %X\n", addr);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `struct in_addr` looks like this:

```
   struct in_addr {
       uint32_t       s_addr;     /* address in network byte order */
   };
```

You can use the `s_addr` field to access the raw bytes of the address.  Pass this to `ntohl` and assign the result to a `uint32_t`, then you can apply bitmasks to it to determine the address class.

Comment: ntohl will convert the network byte to host-order and the class of the address is determined in the network order. I guess it will be a problem.

Comment: @VijayAntony The class is determined by the value of the address.  You want the value in host byte order so you can work on it properly.